# SSIS FK constraint error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, constraints

I have an SSIS package that loads the parent record in a table named `Incident` in a field, `Id`.  There are 5 child tables that have FK constraints to the parent `Incident.Id`.  I have the parent package set up with precedence constraints to each of the child processes.  However all the child packages fail when the FK constraint is in place.

If I remove the constraint once the package finishes I can see that all the Parent IDs entered in the child tables exist.

Any ideas why the process thinks my parent records don't exist?

Comment: Any form of caching of the parent table when the parent package starts maybe?

Comment: Can you show some screenshots?   I have done what you are doing successfully before, so I know it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Really I need some more information about your Packages and the order of execution. But I can say that you have to be aware that the order of insert in package is very important. At first you have to insert parent table and after that you have to start to import data for child table.

If you have one page for each table, It will be good idea to create a master package to manage all of your package.

If you have a full load process, remember that before load master table, you have to empty all record in child table.

If you can give more information I can say what is exact problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I will hopefully have some time next week to post some screen shots and provide additional details.